# Badge proposal: Citizen

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

Today it's very difficult to determine the real involvement of a member in a given community without analysing his profile activity and badges.

By **involvement** I don't mean **performance** (such as reputation, good answer/question badges, etc). Some users may be very active but do not have any major badges like Civic Duty, Electorate or Fanatic. However, their involvement is valuable and they deserve some distinction. They must be distinguished from occasional users.

I suggest a new silver badge that will tag a given user with a sort of citizenship to the community.

> **Citizen** — Has posted at least a question, answer or comment with at least one upvote 20 times a month for the last 6 months.

That badge should be permanent. Real world example: my mother was born in Italy and immigrated to Belgium when she was 17 years old. She still can vote in Italy and also in Belgium where she has citizenship thanks to her involvement (not performance). She has both citizenships.

We may use that badge to determine who is able to vote in the future election.

That badge is easier to get than Fanatic, but harder than Commentator or even Yearling.

Comment: Some people take a week or so of holiday sometimes.

Comment: @ChrisW: we can adjust it on the month instead of week. I update my suggestion.

Comment: We already have a long-term gauge of activity... reputation.

Comment: I like this.  From your description it means that all 
I need to do is post twice a week for 6 months, then I gt the badge and 
I don't need to participate ever again - the badge remains?

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Citizen should be recognized by they involvement not their performance. That's the idea.

Comment: @Pollyanna: I don't know. I don't have access to stats, so I don't know what values should be appropriate; But the badge should not be related to any performance (such as good answers or questions and reputation)

Comment: @Pierre What I meant to ask is - So once I get the badge, I can stop contributing and the badge will remain?  If so, then it's not terribly useful - all it means is that at one point in time the user was active, but says nothign about how active they are on average, or recently.  I would get it, despite pretty much dropping out of stackoverflow for over a year.

Comment: @Pollyanna: I think yes, just like my mother. Because of your involvement you have: 1. A link to the community, you were there for a year 2. You know the community enough to vote for the best moderator

Comment: In order to only reward good participation I think each one should have to have at least one upvote or accept.

Comment: Brilliant link with future elections.

Comment: BalusC: I have some ideas for future elections too, will post them after they are finished.

Comment: @Pierre - "I have some ideas for future elections too, which this comment is too small to contain."  ftfy.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get why the 6 months matter, since the criteria seems to be 20 times in a single month.

Comment: @waiwai: My interpretation is that they must post an upvoted question/answer/comment 20 times each month for six months to get the badge.

Comment: I dunno I think 20 is a little tough. It could be 5 or something and the badge could be bronze. More to show "You hang around here from time to time." Like someone already mentioned Rep is a good indicator of how people perform.

Answer (score 1):

Its good but its like the mixture of several other badges.
How about this:

**Citizen** or **All-rounder** : Has posted  a question,an answer and a comment ,all with at least one upvote on the same day for 10 (or whatever you like) times a month.