# Moderator nomination UI doesn't warn users about character limit

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, usability, nominations

**This is unhelpful:**

[image]

**Especially** when the entered text has less than 1200 characters (according to `wc -c`)!

Now I realise that the site might count differently from `wc` (for instance `wc` doesn’t consider line breaks) but this is no excuse to make the UI unhelpful.

If such arbitrary restrictions must be implemented then it must be made sure that they don’t get in the way.

Especially since this could be fixed so easily: the message claims that I entered more than 1200 characters. Fair enough. **Show me how many characters I have entered!** In real time, of course – so I don’t have to submit the form to see that I have to prune the text.

Comment: +1 for it not displaying a character count when a limit is set.

Comment: By the way, “arbitrary” doesn’t imply useless: I’m all in favour of restricting the length of moderation blurbs.

Comment: Is this restriction absent on Stack Overflow, and/or was it only recently implemented? Because, you know, some of us have had crazy long nominations and they seem to get by just fine...

Comment: @BoltClock No idea … this is from the current nominations at Skeptics.StackExchange.com.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if they're trying to respond to some of the comments here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112844/remove-candidate-stump-speeches-on-election-page . I'd still like to see the collapsed-by-default option myself, instead of a specific length restriction.

Comment: It looks like this is now in place on SO for the current election.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The next build will include a character count while editing your nomination.